# Can not change output for multiplot mode, GNUPLOT?

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to plot multiple output files in gnuplot using "do for sprintf". My code is

```
reset
#set encoding utf8
set encoding iso_8859_1
set terminal postscript eps enhanced color font 'Times-Bold' 25

do for [t=1:4] {

#set output 'LeftChiral_DOS.png'
set output sprintf('Trial-Ru%d-d-up.eps',t)

set size  1.0, 0.94

datafile1 = sprintf('Ru%d-up.dat',t)
datafile2 = sprintf('Ru%d-down.dat',t)


set multiplot layout 1,2

set style data linespoints
#
set origin 0.2, 0

set  noxzeroaxis
set tics out
set border linewidth 2.
set style line 1 lc rgb "red" lt 1 lw 1.5 pt 7
set style line 2 lc rgb "blue" lt 1 lw 2.0
set style line 3 lc rgb "green" lt 1 lw 2.0
set style line 4 lc rgb "black" lt 2 lw 1.5 dt 2
#
set key
set key vertical at 0.9,1.6
set key font ",20"
set noxtics
set ylabel "Energy (eV)"
set xtics ( " {/Symbol G} " 0, " Y " 0.09049, " C " 0.14273, " Z "   0.23322," D " 0.27012, " E " 0.36061," A " 0.41285, " B " 0.50334, " {/Symbol G} " 0.54024)

set origin 0.1,0

set yrange[   -8.0:   4.0]
set xrange[   0.000:    0.54024 ]
 unset key
 weight=15

 plot datafile1 u ($1):2:($3*weight) every 3 w points lw 2 lc rgb "#FF0000" pt 6

 plot datafile2 u ($1):2:($3*weight) every 3 w points lw 2 lc rgb "#FF0000" pt 6
 }
```

As you can see I used do for and sprintf to output multiple files for each value of t variable.

But gnuplot giving me error "Cannot change output for multiplot mode"

Can anyone please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: I think you can use `set output "Trial-Ru".t."-d-up.eps"` instead of your `sprintf`

Answer (score 4):

So I was wrong in my comment. You just need to `unset multiplot` before setting again the output. So here a minimal example to make your error again (using minimal example is important when you post on stackoverflow)

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot
set term pdf
do for [t=1:4] {

  set output "test_".t.".pdf"
  set multiplot

  f(x)=x*t
  g(x)=-x*t
  set xrange [0:100]
  plot g(x)
  plot f(x)
}
```

By adding `unset multiplot` at the end, you will create you four multiplot files without errors:

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot
set term pdf
do for [t=1:4] {

  set output "test_".t.".pdf"
  set multiplot

  f(x)=x*t
  g(x)=-x*t
  set xrange [0:100]
  plot g(x)
  plot f(x)
  unset multiplot
}
```

I suppose that's because as said by the [manual](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node203.html):

> The command set multiplot places gnuplot in the multiplot mode, in
>   which several plots are placed on the same page, window, or screen.

it makes no sense to put plots in different files while putting them in the same file.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. It indeed worked for me. It appears to be unset multiplot within do loop is important. Many thanks again.